# Multiple Rewrites with nginx ingress annotations on Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I believe that I must create multiple `Ingress` resources to achieve the desired effect, but must ask, is it possible to have multiple rewrite annotations with nginx (community) controller for the same host?

I have the following, but it won't work, as I understand it, because there is no way to link the rewrite rule to the path explicitly. In this case, I suppose it could use the fact that there are different numbers of capture groups, but that wouldn't always be the case.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: api-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: https://staging.example.com/keyword-lnk/badnewsbears/$1/$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: https://staging.example.com/lnk/$2
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: staging-letsencrypt-prod

spec:
  rules:
    - host: staging.example.com
      http:
        paths:
         - path: /
           backend:
              serviceName: api-service
              servicePort: http
    - host: badnewsbears.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: api-service
              servicePort: http
            path: ^(/a/)(.*)$
          - backend:
              serviceName: api-service
              servicePort: http
            path: ^/([tbc])/(.*)
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - staging.example.com
    - badnewsbears.example.com
    secretName: letsencrypt-prod-issuer-account-key
    # ^ must be set to the key matching the annotation
    # certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer above
```

The goal is to have requests to `staging.example.com` not have rewrites, but requests to `badnewsbears.example.com/t/soup` rewrite to `https://staging.example.com/keyword-lnk/badnewsbears/t/soup`, while
`badnewsbears.example.com/a/soup` yields `https://staging.example.com/lnk/$2`

Is there a way to specify a mapping of rewrite target->path in the `Ingress` (or elsewhere), or will I have to separate out the different rewrite rules for the same host into different

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR; you're not really meant to be able to configure multiple rewrites for the kubernetes/ingress-nginx controller type. Although it is possible to hack this together in a limited fashion using regex based rewrites with capture groups, as explained in this answer I posted to [How to proxy_pass with nginx-ingress?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57822415/207488)
.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Would it work to use multiple Ingresses for the same host? Or is that not possible. I don't anticipate a great number of rewrite rules per host (around 2), but I do want to be able to easily add a new host. If that means adding 1 Ingress per rewrite/host, it could be manageable.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can create multiple ingresses with the same host and different path applying the annotation. So that would be the solution you suspected in the first place.
2. You could consider trying [Nginx Plus based Ingress](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/master/docs/nginx-plus.md#nginx-ingress-controller-with-nginx-plus).

> To configure URI rewriting you need to add the `nginx.org/rewrites`
>   annotation to your Ingress resource definition. The annotation syntax
>   is as follows:

```
nginx.org/rewrites: "serviceName=service1 rewrite=rewrite1[;serviceName=service2 rewrite=rewrite2;...]"
```

Here is the official [example](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/rewrites#example).

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: That annotation is for the nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress, but this question is targeting the kubernetes/ingress-nginx, as indicated by the ingress snippet in the question. Here is a description of the differences between these two types of nginx ingress controller: https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/master/docs/nginx-ingress-controllers.md

Comment: Are you certain that you can create multiple ingresses with the same host and apply rewrite rules to each one independently? I've been trying just that, and inspecting the nginx config, and it looks like they all get merged together.

Comment: new official example: https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/main/examples/ingress-resources/rewrites